# adding a UIViewController to a box2D project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have been working with cocos2D and developed a project from an example project for cocos2D.  This project uses no UIViewcontroller and I want to add elements via the interface builder.

Am I thinking right that I can add a UIViewController and have all the physics interactions in this (on top of) this UIView?

I've tooled around with adding a UIViewcontroller to this project, but seem to get lost on how to start this correctly (thus, I've had no luck)

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use Interface Builder to create any type of Cocos2d app entirely. I say entirely because there are ways to have half and half.